# Efficiently computing the digits of irrational number

Tags: nt.number-theory, transcendental-number-theory

Is there irrational real number $C$, defined by algebraic numbers and elementary functions such that the $n$-th digit in base $b$ in the fractional part
is computable in time polynomial in $\log{n}$?

Closed form for the $n$-th digit is $\lfloor b^n C \rfloor \mod b$.

For some $C$ defined by "artificial" series like 
$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{b^{k^2}}$ it is possible.

Another island of tractability is the rational number 
$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n}{10^n}$.

Possible approach might be [BB Plouffe type formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bailey%E2%80%93Borwein%E2%80%93Plouffe_formula).

**EDIT**

I am looking for $C$ with closed form algebraic numbers and elementary functions, not $C$ defined by simple series.

Comment: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}10^{-n!}$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thanks. What is the closed form with elementary function of your series?
I gave similar example lacking closed form in the question.

Comment: I thought the examples in your question were meant to be examples of the kind of thing you wanted – are you saying they are examples of the kind of thing you don't want? Anyway, I think $f(n)=1$ if $n=k!$ for some $k$, else, zero, is an elementary function, and the number I gave is defined using it. If that's not what you want, please edit your question to clarify.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I edited, is it clear enough? Indeed my example is not of simple form, just gave it to show series approach might be possible.

Comment: "with closed form algebraic numbers and elementary functions" is still not very clear.